# Delphi - Binary OR values from an enumerated type

Tags: delphi, enumeration

I have a variable declared from an enumerated type. I would like to binary `OR` values from this enumeration to the variable.

```
type
  TValues = (vValue1 = $01, vValue2 = $02);

procedure BinaryOR;
var
  Value : TValues;
begin
  Value := Value or vValue1;
end;
```

But it seems like Delphi is not happy with this, as it gives a compiler error:

> E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

How would I go about doing this? I mean I could work with integer data types and `OR` the values from the enumeration, but I would prefer if the variable is of the enumeration type.

**Additional Info**

There seems to be a lot of questions regarding why I would like to do this or a better explanation of the actual implementation. I did solve the problem since I posted the question.

I prefer to work with enumerated types since it constrains the implementation to a specific set of values. I have an 8bit value in a protocol that is communicated between devices. This value can hold multiple states. Each bit respresents a state. I was looking for a way to OR the values together such that I can populate the value with the required states using enumerated types.

Just using single seperate constants allows room for populating the value with values from outside the defined set. I was trying to avoid this.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you really need to do this, use `Ord(vValue1)`. Works: `ShowMessage(IntToStr(Ord(vValue1) or Ord(vValue2)));`

Comment: Won't the `TValuesSet = set of TValues;`  be what you are looking for?

Comment: `type TValue = (vValue1 = $01, vValue2 = $02); TValues = set of TValue` is what you are looking for. Because `$01` is a value, not "a values", just like a Peugeot is a car, not "a cars".

Comment: This Q is confusing: Do you want to work with sets of values, and compute a union, or do you want really to compute the `or` of two bitfield constants? In the last case, it doesn't make any sense to expect the result to be "of the enumerated type" or even of a set of that type.

Comment: **Bitwise `or` expects `Integer` operands and incompatible with `Enumerated`.** Perhaps you should add more details or better some explanation on what you are trying to achieve, because the "_How would I go_" part is unanswerable besides simple highlighted statement above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible in this way. A variable of an enumerated type can hold only one distinct value at a time:

```
procedure EnumTest
type
  TValues = (vValue1 = $01, vValue2 = $02);
var
  Value : TValues;
begin
  Value := vValue1;
  Value := vValue2;
end;
```

If you want to save several enum values in one variable, you can use a `set` as shown in the following example. But please note, that these can't be `or`ed together, too! For this you need to typecast the enum values to `integer` using `Ord` and then use the `or` operator on these values.

```
type
  TValues = (vValue1 = $01, vValue2 = $02);
  TValuesSet = set of TValues;
var
  Value: TValues;
  Values : TValuesSet;
  i: integer;
begin
  Values := [vValue1, vValue2];
  //or
  Include(Values, vValue1);
  Include(Values, vValue2);

  i := 0;

  // or'ing all the values in a set
  for Value in Values do
    i := i or Ord(Value);

  Writeln(i);

  // or'ing plain enum values
  i := Ord(vValue1) or Ord(vValue2);
  Writeln(i);
  Readln;
end.
```

Output:

> 3
> 3

Comment: You should not be using casts and or to perform this operation with sets. Use the + operator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is not about adding different sets, or what do you mean?

Comment: The `+` operator for sets is the same as bitwise `or` for bitsets. So you can use `Include` and `+` and avoid casting to integer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please give me an example of what you mean. When I use the ``+`` operator on set values I can add them to the set, but how does this give me the expected end result?

Comment: Set operators are documented: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You still refuse to answer my question properly. I can't find anything in the linked doc about what I am doing in my example above.

Comment: The major problem is that the Q is ambiguous, almost nonsensical. Does the OP want to compute a union of two sets (of car manufacturers, say), or does the OP want to compute the `or` of two (or more) bitfield constants, that happen to belong to some enumeration, and hopes that by chance the result also happens to be in the same enumeration.

Comment: In your example above, you use `or`. That can be replaced by `+` or `Include` if you convert `i` into a set. For integer bitsets, `or` is used to perform the same operation as `+` / `Include` with Delphi sets. I said that in my second comment. I don't think I can explain set operators to you, if you don't understand them, in comments. As @AndreasRejbrand says though, the question is weak and unclear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand sets quite well, I think.^^ But with the method you mention you don't get the result where the values are bitwise or'ed together like I do in the loop. I also showed the usage of ``Include`` already in my example.

Comment: @DelphiCoder I don't think you understand the + operator for sets. It's not the same as for integers. So `[foo] + [foo] = [foo]` in just the same way as `x or x = x` using bitwise or on integers.

Comment: I understood that already, don't worry.